# How to click the 2nd text box with smae class name in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

I have recently started using selenium with python and stuck with the below problem. It may be simple but I have tried a lot while searching through different answers but could not solve it.
I want to click the 2nd text box with class name 'param-text-input text-input numeric-value'

```
    <div class="bet-widget-main-row-right">
      <div class="bet-widget-main-content">
        <div class="bet-params">
           <div class="param-wrapper">
              <span class="param-label">Label1</span>
              <div class="param-input -desktop">
                <div class="param with-error">
                  <span class="param-input-wrapper">
                    <span class="param-currency numeric-value">£</span>
                    <input type="text" class="param-text-input text-input numeric-value" value=".04" tabindex="0" size="3" maxlength="11">
                  </span>
                </div>
              <div class="param-input_ticks"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="param-wrapper">
            <span class="param-label">Label2</span>
            <div class="param-input -desktop">
              <div class="param">
                <span class="param-input-wrapper">
                  <input type="text" class="param-text-input text-input numeric-value" value="2.18" tabindex="0" size="4" maxlength="8">
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="param-input_ticks"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="bet-submit"><button class="confirm-bet-button -accented micro-button" type="submit" disabled="" tabindex="0"><span>Button1</span></button></div></div>
```

I have tried multiple solutions but none work:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@class='param-text-inp‌​ut.text-input.numeri‌​c-value'][2]").clear‌​() 

self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[input.param-text-‌​input.text-input.num‌​eric-value][2]").cle‌​ar() 

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='param-tex‌​t-input'][2]").clear‌​()
```

Any pointers/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that you would prefer to use a CSS selector, the following will choose that second input:

```
div.param-wrapper:nth-of-type(2) input.param-text-input.text-input.numeric-value
```

we're looking for the second "param-wrapper" because that is the thing which will correctly count the parameters.

Comment: worked like a charm.. did not want to use xpath unless there was no option. hopefully other suggested solutions are correct as well.

Comment: @Nik You did show us your code trial for xpath within the question & didn't leave a clue that you are preferring css. I think the xpath based Answers needs a evaluation from your side as well. After a lot of study it's still inconclusive whether css or xpath which gives better performance. Some Answer are better constructed ☺

Comment: @DebanjanB I am quite new to stackoverflow as far as my usage of the platform goes so excuse me for the incomplete information in my question. I am still learning and will do better with support from people like you over the platform :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy:

```
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@Class="param-text-‌​input.text-input.num‌​eric-value"]')[1].clear()
```

or

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@Class="param-text-‌​input.text-input.num‌​eric-value"]')[1].send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

You need to make an object list in the first place. So you should find all the placeholders with the same name. Then get said item, which is the second element(list are zero based, so 1 is second)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in XPath to select the n-th object that corresponds to your XPath expression.

To achieve this you use the `[n]` at the end of of your expression.

What you forgot is to put `()` around your expression before adding the `[n]`.

So your XPath should be `(//input[@class='param-tex‌​t-input'])[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

To click the `2nd text box with class name 'param-text-input text-input numeric-value'` you can use the following code block :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='bet-params']//following-sibling::input[2]").clear()
```